# Forwarding, masking and aliasing with Apache version 2xy

Tags: linux, perl, apache, http

What if I want to forward `example.net` to `example.net`

What does the visitor see?

- As a site?
- What does the adress bar display?

Is it possible to do a forwarding that shows the domain name `example.com` in the adress bar, and that it shows the content of `example.net`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `mod_proxy` using a combination of the [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [`ProxyPassReverse`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directives.

Comment: hello Borodin and faffaff- many many thanks for the quick reply This is good news! i will use the mentioned Apache things